# Sum of two numbers with prompt

Tags: javascript, sum, prompt

I've been trying to solve this problem for the last couple days: when I subtract, multiply or divide 2 numbers input through a prompt, everything works fine; but when I want to add them, I get the 2 numbers simply written together.

Example: if I add 5 and 6, I get 56!!

Here's the code I'm working with.

```js
var a = prompt("Enter first number");
var b = prompt("Enter second number");

alert(a + b);
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to specify the value type?

Comment: try with alert(parseInt(a)+parseInt(b));

Comment: @harsha that worked! thank you! I still haven't learned about parseInt, so I guess I have bitten off more than I could chew..

Comment: If you want to use `parseInt` make sure you [completely understand all of its quirks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 10):

The function `prompt` returns a string and `+` is (unwisely, perhaps) used for *both* string concatenation and number addition.

You do not "specify types" in JavaScript but you can do string to number conversion at run time.  There are many ways to so this.  The simplest is:

```
var a = +prompt("Enter first number");
var b = +prompt("Enter second number");
alert(a + b);
```

but you can also do

```
var a = Number(prompt("Enter first number"));
var b = Number(prompt("Enter second number"));
alert(a + b);
```

(Avoid `parseInt` because it only handles the leading characters and will not add numbers like 4.5 and 2.6.)

Comment: I guess parseFloat will ?

Comment: `parseFloat` will handle 4.5 but try it with 4.5xyz as well.  Do you want to accept that?  If not, stick to `Number` or the simple `+`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JavaScript is loosely typed. So, it doesn't know that "5" is a number, actually, because everything you receive from a prompt is String.

You can do:

```
var a = prompt("1st") * 1;
var b = prompt("2nd") * 1;

alert (a + b);
```

This works because the * operator forces everything to act like numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using concatination operation instead of arithmetic operator.

In your above code:

```
alert(a + b);
```

Your browser compiler will assume it as concatination. So it concatinating two strings. That is why you are getting that output.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter var a and var b, the variables are probably set strings(characters) and not as integers.

So, when you use `a + b`, your'e putting those characters together.

For ensuring that the value you enter saves as an integer, you can you use the

```
parseInt()
```

For example: `var a = parseInt( prompt("Enter first number") );`

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
var a = prompt("Enter first number");
var b = prompt("Enter second number");
var x=parseInt(a);
var y=parseInt(b);

alert(x+y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter first number"));
var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter second number"));
alert(a + b);
```

You use the parseInt before the prompt because its will take as input as string if you use the parseInt it will take as the number.

Answer (score 0):

1) The function  **`prompt`** returns a string and **'+'** is (unwisely, perhaps) used for both string concatenation and number addition.

```
var a = +prompt("Enter first number");
var b = +prompt("Enter second number");
alert(a + b);
```

2.)some developers use `parseInt`before prompt ,But its not good way because that not add floating numbers like 5.2 ,9.99 etc

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter first number"));
var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter second number"));
alert(a + b);
```

**BEST WAY**
You can do with other different method for add number in prompt box put `Number` before prompt.

```
var a = Number(prompt("Enter first number"));
var b = Number(prompt("Enter second number"));
alert(a + b);
```

JavaScript is loosely coupled.

Comment: V., this just looks like an exact copy and paste of [Ray's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22705061/1366033).  Can you highlight what is different or what changes you think that needs

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
        var a = prompt("Enter first number","");
        var b = prompt("Enter second number","");
        a=Number(a);
        b=Number(b);
        alert(a+b);
 </script>
```

This will also work converting a String to Number and alert.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
   let number1 = prompt("Enter your 1st Number: ");
    let number2 = prompt("Enter your 2nd Number: ");
    let result = parseFloat(number1) + parseFloat(number2);
    alert(result);
    
</script>
```

Comment: You should stick to the variable names used in the question. Also a little bit of explanation would be more than welcome

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this.

```
let q1 = prompt("Value 1");
let q2 = prompt("Value 2");
let total = Number(q1) + Number(q2);
document.write(total);
```