# Why can't I add an integer and variable in the console log?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to print number + 1 in the console log but instead of adding the numbers together, it concatenates them. What am I doing wrong? For instance, if the user inputs 7, instead of getting 8, it will print 17.

```
let number = prompt('what is your favorite number')
if(number == 42){
  console.log("Yay! That's my favorite too!")
} else if (number < 42){
  console.log("Eh, that's OK but " + (1 + number) + " would have been better")
} else{
  console.log("LAME. That number is too large!")
}


console.log()
```

If a user inputs a number less than 42, it should add 1 to the entered number and print that number. However, the current code is concatenating 1 to the number.

Comment: This is because javascript is a dynamic typed language, it can convert numbers to strings based on the context, try `number*1`, this is clearly a number operation so javascript will treat number as a number and not as a string.

Comment: parseInt(number) will solve your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of two numbers with prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704963/sum-of-two-numbers-with-prompt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prompt` returns a string... you need to convert it to a number, for example with

```
number = +number;
```

before using it as a number

Answer (score 1):

You can use as it will consider it a string while performing arithmatic operations

```
number = Number(number)
```

You will get more details about this wrapper object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Answer (score 0):

That is because **prompt** returns a string.
So if you enter **21** for example and add **1** the result will be **211**.

You need to convert number to a number right after prompt like:

```
number = parseInt(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value returned from executing `prompt` is a string rather than a number. You need to parse the string into a number using `parseInt`[1], or if you're allowing floats `parseFloat`[2].

For example:

```js
let response = prompt('what is your favorite number')
let number = parseInt(response, 10) // Convert response into a string
if(number == 42){
  console.log("Yay! That's my favorite too!")
} else if (number < 42){
  console.log("Eh, that's OK but " + (1 + number) + " would have been better")
} else{
  console.log("LAME. That number is too large!")
}


console.log()
```

References

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat