# Output come as string

Tags: javascript

I just want to add two numbers but is result come as string . I use vscode.How can take input as integer ?

var num1 =prompt("enter a number");
var num2=prompt("enter a number");

var sum =num1+num2;

console.log(`the of ${num1}  and ${num2}  ${sum}` );

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+sum+two+prompts) of [Sum of two numbers with prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22704963/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change them to type `Number` before you can add them. User input from `prompt()` will always return a string. Try:

```
var sum = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use parseInt() or parseFloat() function, which is used for converting string to Int or Float type.

```
var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parseInt(), or the parseFloat() function. These convert String to Int/Float type.

`var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);`